# Room treatment: how much energy can a Helmholtz resonator absorb?

Tags: acoustics

A common suggestion to dampen low frequencies in a room (and to shorten the reverberation time) is to use a Helmholtz resonator. This is typically just an airtight, rigid box with one or more vents and some rockwool inside. It is ideally placed at an edge or a corner of the room to be treated. Unlike porous absorbers which act on sound *velocity* (which approaches zero near a wall), a Helmholtz resonator acts on the sound *pressure*.

A perfect absorber is often pictured as a hole in the wall, were sound energy leaves the room forever. The larger the hole, the more absorption you get. However, the only way a Helmholtz resonator can interact with the sound in the room is through its vents. The area of the vents is quite small, compared to the area of the walls. I wouldn't expect much absorption if I cut a hole of equal size through the wall (though I might be wrong here).

- Can a Helmholtz resonator "catch" more sound than what hits the vents?
- Otherwise, would it be advisable to maximize the area of the vents (requiring a longer tube to achieve the same resonance frequency)?